# How to set threshold for bias in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, bias

I have a large dataset containing the fitting results which contains ~10k observations. The dataset includes ~10k predicted values and actual values for different datasets, and we define $bias_i = actual_i - predicted_i$, and overall bias is mean(bias). I need to evaluate whether the bias is large enough or not, so we want to set a threshold. I see one people using 1.5 * std(bias) as the threshold, and if overall bias < 1.5 * std(bias), the model performs well. But I cannot understand why 1.5 * std(bias) can be the threshold. Any help would be appreciated.

My initial thought is: there might be a hypothesis test to test $H_0$: overall bias = 0. and set the confidence interval $[0 ± z*std(bias)/ \sqrt{n}]$, where they set $z/ \sqrt{n}$ = 1.5. I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: In order to set a threshold, it will be important to say what you want to use that threshold to do and why you want to do that.